# Trouble With Htaccess Query

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have an wordpress products home page with this link: **www.example.com/products/**

And i also create custom product pages with this kind of urls: **www.example.com/products/black-helmet**

Now.. my htaccess file include this line:

```
RewriteRule ^products/(.*) products.php?name=$1
```

How can i add, 'if there is **no** variable in **products/(.*)**, use the wordpress original page which linked **www.example.com/products/**.. else, **products.php?name=$1** ?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
#1--if the request is "/products/" , let it pass through unchanged--#   
RewriteRule ^products/?$ - [L]
#2--if the request is "/product/foobar" ,rewrite it to "/products.php?name=foobar--#
RewriteRule ^products/(.+) products.php?name=$1 [L]
```